# Slide.js slider changes background to blue when the RIGHT slider scroll button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The [website](http://www.adnmusc.ca) is live and you can see how the slider changes the background to blue when the right scrollbar is clicked.

Any inputs on how this can be fixed , I have tried the JS, CSS. 
If anyone can see it in the fire bug and point me in the right direction than it would be great.

Thanks.
[Here is the screenshot of the slider after the right scroll is clicked multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egnx6.png)

Comment: What do you mean ? I do not see any problem when I click on the right arrow into the slider. The only blue thing I see triggers when I double-click.

Comment: I don't see any blue background. Please elaborate on your question. You might want to show an image so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Arbuste..you got it that is exactly what I am talking about. It does not happen on the left slider scroll button.
@magreenberg
Even the #slide is set to display:none in CSS and the JS property that I can think of is the following one that could be affecting it :
`code`
             pauseOnHover: false,
                effect: "slide"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Add this to your CSS.

```
.slidesjs-container {
    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
    -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
    -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none;          /* Likely future */      
}
```

This css property makes it so an element can not be high-lighted.

Comment: No problem, please mark as answer if it was helpful to you.